# JavaScript returning multiple times when using return

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to recieve data of multiple JSON files. I have the data I need, but multiple times, even though I use a return statement. I need the data from the `getData()` function. Which needs to progress to the `loadImage()` function. I have no clue why the code returns the same multiple times.

Thanks in advance.

My Chrome Developer Console:
[image]

My Directory Structure:
[image]

My code:

```
// var defaultHairData = require(['json!../character/hair/data.json'], function(data) {
//   console.log("1", data);
// });
// var defaultHeadData = require("../character/head/data.json");
// var defaultLeftArmData = require("../character/leftArm/data.json");
// var defaultLegsData = require("../character/legs/data.json");
// var defaultRightArmData = require("../character/rightArm/data.json");
// var defaultTorsoData = require("../character/torso/data.json");

// var defaultHairImage = require("../character/hair/0/hair.png");
// var defaultHeadImage = require("../character/head/0/head.png");
// var defaultLeftArmImage = require("../character/leftArm/0/leftArm.png");
// var defaultLeftArmJumpImage = require("../character/leftArm_jump/0/leftArm_jump.png"); // Jump!
// var defaultLegsImage = require("../character/legs/0/legs.png");
// var defaultLegsJumpImage = require("../character/legs_jump/0/legs_jump.png"); // Jump!
// var defaultRightArmImage = require("../character/rightArm/0/rightArm.png");
// var defaultRightArmJumpImage = require("../character/rightArm_jump/0/rightArm_jump.png"); // Jump!
// var defaultTorsoImage = require("../character/torso/0/torso.png");

var character = {
  name: "Homie",
  jumping: false
}
var totalResources = 9;
var loadedResources = 0;
var fps = 30;
var characterXPos = 245;
var characterYPos = 185;
var characterEyesOpenTime = 0;
var characterMaxEyesHeight = 14;
var characterCursiveEyeHeight = characterMaxEyesHeight;
var characterTimeBetweenBlinks = 4000;
var characterBlinkUpdateTime = 200;
var characterBlinkTimer = setInterval(updateBlink, characterBlinkUpdateTime);
var FPSInterval = setInterval(updateFPS, 1000);
var characterCanvas;
var characterCanvasContext;
var breathAmount = 0;
var breathMax = 2;
var breathIncrease = 0.1;
var breathDirection = 1;
var breathInterval = setInterval(updateBreathing, 1000 / fps);
var cursiveFPS = 0;
var framesDrawn = 0;

window.defaultHairData = {};

function updateFPS() {
  cursiveFPS = framesDrawn;
  framesDrawn = 0;
}

// This is where I need the data from \/
function getData(characterPart) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", `./character/${characterPart}/data.json`);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log("Yoink", window.defaultData);
      return window.defaultData = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Could not get file with the name "data.json" in the directory "${characterPart}".`);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

async function prepareCharacterCanvas(canvasContainer, canvasWidth, canvasHeight) {
  characterCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  characterCanvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
  characterCanvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
  characterCanvas.setAttribute('id', 'gameCanvas');
  canvasContainer.appendChild(characterCanvas);

  if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
    characterCanvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(characterCanvas);
  };
  characterCanvasContext = characterCanvas.getContext('2d');
  characterCanvas.width = characterCanvas.width;
  characterCanvasContext.fillText("Loading...", 40, 140);

  // This is where the data needs to come from
  await getData("hair");
  await getData("head");
  await getData("leftArm");
  await getData("legs");
  await getData("rigthArm");
  await getData("torso");

  loadImage(`${defaultData.filename}`);
  loadImage(`${defaultHeadData.filename}`);
  loadImage(`${defaultLeftArmData.filename}`);
  loadImage(`${defaultLegsData.filename}`);
  loadImage(`${defaultRightArmData.filename}`);
  loadImage(`${defaultTorsoData.filename}`);
}

function loadImage(datatags, picture) {
  var generateButtons = Boolean;

  if (datatags.filename !== picture.name) {
    throw new Error("Datatag 'filename' must be the same as the picture name!");
  } else {
    if (datatags.fileExtension !== "png") {
      throw new Error("Datatag 'fileExtension' must be png!");
    } else {
      if (datatags.customizeable === false) {
        generateButtons = false;
      } else {
        generateButtons = true;
      }

      if (generateButtons === true) {
        // Generate buttons here!
      }

      if (datatags.changesIfJumping === true) {
        // Load normal image first here
        var pic = new Image();
        pic.onload = function() {
          resourceIsLoaded();
        }
        pic.src = `../character/${datatags.filename}/0/${datatags.filename}.png`;

        // Load image if jumping next
        var jumpingPic = new Image();
        jumpingPic.onload = function() {
          resourceIsLoaded();
        }
        jumpingPic.src = `../character/${datatags.filename}_jump/0/${datatags.filename}_jump.png`;
      }

      var pic = new Image();
      pic.onload = function() {
        resourceIsLoaded();
      }
      pic.src = `../character/${datatags.filename}/0/${datatags.filename}.png`;
    }
  }
  var pic = new Image();
  pic.onload = function() {
    resourceIsLoaded();
  };
  pic.src = `${pic}`;
};

function resourceIsLoaded() {
  loadedResources += 1;
  if (loadedResources === totalResources) {
    setInterval(redrawCharacter(), 1000 / userFPS);
  };
};

function redrawCharacter() {
  var x = characterXPos;
  var y = characterYPos;
  var jumpHeight = 45;
  characterCanvas.width = characterCanvas.width;

  if (character.jumping === true) {
    drawEyes(x + 40, y + 29, 100 - breathAmount, 4);
    y -= jumpHeight;
    characterCanvasContext.drawImage("leftArm_jump", x + 40, y - 42 - breathAmount);
    characterCanvasContext.drawImage("legs_jump", x, y - 6);
    characterCanvasContext.drawImage("rightArm_jump", x - 35, y - 42 - breathAmount);
  } else {
    drawEyes(x + 40, y + 29, 160 - breathAmount, 6);
    characterCanvasContext.drawImage("leftArm", x + 40, y - 42 - breathAmount);
    characterCanvasContext.drawImage("legs", x, y);
    characterCanvasContext.drawImage("rightArm", x - 15, y - 42 - breathAmount);
  };
  characterCanvasContext.drawImage("torso", x, y - 50);
  characterCanvasContext.drawImage("head", x - 10, y - 125 - breathAmount);
  characterCanvasContext.drawImage("hair", x - 37, y - 138 - breathAmount);
  characterCanvasContext.drawEyes(x + 47, y - 68 - breathAmount, 8, characterCursiveEyeHeight);
  characterCanvasContext.drawEyes(x + 58, y - 68 - breathAmount, 8, characterCursiveEyeHeight);
};

function drawEyes(centerX, centerY, width, height) {
  characterCanvasContext.beginPath();
  characterCanvasContext.moveTo(centerX, centerY - height / 2);

  characterCanvasContext.bezierCurveTo(
    centerX + width / 2, centerY - height - 2,
    centerX + width / 2, centerY + height / 2,
  centerX, centerY + height / 2);

  characterCanvasContext.bezierCurveTo(
    centerX - width / 2, centerY + height / 2,
    centerX - width / 2, centerY - height / 2,
  centerX, centerY - height / 2);

  characterCanvasContext.fillStyle = "black";
  characterCanvasContext.fill();
  characterCanvasContext.closePath();
};

function updateBreathing() {
  if (breathDirection === 1) {
    breathAmount -= breathIncrease;
    if (breathAmount < -breathMax) {
      breathDirection = -1;
    };
  } else {
    breathAmount += breathIncrease;
    if (breathAmount > breathMax) {
      breathDirection = 1;
    };
  };
};

function updateBlink() {
  characterEyesOpenTime += characterBlinkUpdateTime;
  if (characterEyesOpenTime >= characterTimeBetweenBlinks) {
    blink();
  };
};

function blink() {
  characterCursiveEyeHeight -= 1;
  if (characterCursiveEyeHeight <= 0) {
    characterEyesOpenTime = 0;
    characterCursiveEyeHeight = characterMaxEyesHeight;
  } else {
    setTimeout(blink, 10);
  };
};

function jump() {
  if (character.jumping === false) {
    character.jumping = true;
    setTimeout(land, 500);
  };
};

function land() {
  character.jumping = false;
}
```

The JSON file structure:

```
{
    "filename": "legs",
    "fileExtension": "png",
    "changesIfJumping": true,
    "customizeable": true
}
```

Comment: you'll want to use `xhr.onload` instead ... `xhr.onreadystatechange` gets called multiple times in a requests lifecycle - and is old school method anyway

Comment: Using `await` on a function that doesn't return a Promise, doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks! That worked a bit! Now have rightArm and Torso are still missing..

Comment: My bad. Thought the answer was chosen by multiple people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use more modern way - [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead xhr

```js
async function getData(characterPart) {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(`./character/${characterPart}/data.json`);
    return response.json()
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Could not get file with the name "data.json" in the directory "${characterPart}".`);
  }
}


// TEST

async function start() {
  window.defaultData = await getData('xxx');
}

start();
```

Comment: Fun fact: `return await x` and `return x` are the same thing ;)

Comment: yes - surprising - I check [it here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/nLtbpxw9/) - fixed